# is there any short codes approach for conditional statement with relational operation?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, checkbox, conditional-statements

I'm creating this school project of mine, a Laundry Shop System.
It consists a lot of checkboxes to know what is the specific services that customer wants. My question is, is there any coding approach to minimize my conditional if-elseif-endif statement?

My code is look like this:

```
    If chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked And chkPants.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
   'statement goes here........ 
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then  
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkBarong.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    ElseIf chkWashDryFold.Checked And chkWashDryPress.Checked And chkPressOnly.Checked And chkCoat.Checked And chkJacket.Checked And chkPolo.Checked And chkBlouse.Checked And chkSkirt.Checked And chkDress.Checked And chkGown.Checked And chkChildrens.Checked And chkStuff.Checked = True Then
    'statement goes here........
    End if
```

My program is when a user check the 1 checkbox or 2 checkboxes or 3 checkboxes and so on..

Sample Image of my Program that Consists of several checkboxes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3lsP.png

Comment: Try using a `SELECT..CASE` statement for more readability

Comment: What are you doing in the different branches? What's different between each branches?

Comment: thanks for comments, i'll study and try the answer of @tinstaafl. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

One way is with a bit of refactoring.  An instance of a bitwise enum can be used to store the checked state of each checkbox:

```
<Flags()> Public Enum Laundry As Integer
    WashDryFold = 1
    WashDryPress = 2
    PressOnly = 4
    'and so on ...(doubling the value each time)
End Enum
```

Then set the Tag property of the checkboxes to the appropriate enum value:

```
Public LaundrySettings As Laundry
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    CheckBox1.Tag = Laundry.WashDryFold
    CheckBox2.Tag = Laundry.WashDryPress
    CheckBox3.Tag = Laundry.PressOnly
    'and so on ...
End Sub
```

When you're ready to evaluate the checkboxes just build the enum value from the checked boxes and use a select block to do what needs to be done.  Each unique combination of checkboxes will produce a unique value.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    LaundrySettings = New Laundry
    For Each chk As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        If chk.Checked Then
            LaundrySettings = CType(LaundrySettings Or CType(chk.Tag, Laundry), Laundry)
        End If
    Next
    Select Case CInt(LaundrySettings)
        Case 1
        'code here
        Case 2
        'code here
        Case 3
        'code here
        'and so on ...
    End Select
End Sub
```

Just in case LINQ is not an option here's a non-LINQ version:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    LaundrySettings = New Laundry
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If cntrl.Name.StartsWith("chk") Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox)
            If chk.Checked Then
                LaundrySettings = CType(LaundrySettings Or CType(cntrl.Tag, Laundry), Laundry)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Select Case CInt(LaundrySettings)
        Case 1
        'code here
        Case 2
        'code here
        Case 3
            'code here
            'and so on ...
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the useful answer.. im still a newbie in vb.net, but i'll study the interesting code you have given.

Comment: why double the value each time in enum?

Comment: @Mark - Because it's a bitwise enum it's the combination of values that give the enum it's total value.  Basically the same as when you look at a binary number.

Comment: i have problem in  part `Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)`. the error line says the `OfType` is not a member of `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection`, after `Me.Controls` when I press (.)=(dot) there's no `OfType` showing. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark - What version of visual studio are you using?  You may have to `Imports.System.Linq` first.

Comment: @Mark - I added a version that doesn't require `OfType`.

Comment: many thanks for your help. i look forward to it and study your codes. it is confusing to me, because i'm just a beginner in vb.net programming. but i will study it. thanks man.